# Deploying Django project to fly.io

Tags: django, deployment, fly

I'm trying to deploy my Django project on `fly.io`, but I'm encountering an issue where it's creating two machines instead of the desired one. Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
Running nameless-paper-520 release_command: python hw10/manage.py migrate
  release_command 5683d609cd778e completed successfully
This deployment will:
 * create 2 "app" machines

No machines in group app, launching a new machine
Error: error creating a new machine: failed to launch VM: To create more than 1 machine per app please add a payment method.
```

I want to deploy my project with only one machine. I've tried modifying the fly.toml file and setting `max_machines = 1` under the [experimental] section, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Here's my current fly.toml configuration:

`fly.toml`

```
app = "fly-builder-throbbing-forest-5735"
primary_region = "waw"
console_command = "/code/myapp/manage.py shell"

[deploy]
  release_command = "python myapp/manage.py migrate"

[env]
  ...
[http_service]
  internal_port = 8000
  force_https = true
  auto_stop_machines = true
  auto_start_machines = true
  min_machines_running = 0

[[statics]]
  guest_path = "/code/static"
  url_prefix = "/static/"
  
[[services]]
  internal_port = 8000
  protocol = "tcp"
  [services.concurrency]
    hard_limit = 1
    soft_limit = 1

[experimental]
  max_machines = 1
```

I'm using the following `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10

FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir -p /code

WORKDIR /code

RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system
COPY . /code

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8000", "--workers", "2", "myapp.wsgi"]
```

How can I modify my configuration to deploy my Django project with only one machine on fly.io?

Answer (score 2):

If you comment out the [release command](https://fly.io/docs/reference/configuration/#run-one-off-commands-before-releasing-a-deployment) your deployment will succeed.

As can be seen in your deploy log, a release command is run (the database migration). These release commands are run in separate, ephemeral machines and not on the machine that builds/runs your application. Therefore two machines are required which currently doesn't work in the free tier.

If there's no release command but the deploy logs contain the following line:

> Creating a second machine to increase service availability

you'll need to deactivate *high availability* by deploying with `flyctl deploy --ha=false`.

Answer (score 1):

Either `--ha=false` when launching, OR simply do `fly m list` and copy the id - then `fly m stop` and `fly m destroy` the machine. I do this all the time to save my max machines!